# Sending messages from php to java

Tags: java, php, ipc

My app is a feed aggregator. The frontend is programmed in php, but I have a Java program running periodically to update the feeds database. Under the current scheme if a user adds a feed to be aggregated he must have to wait until the aggregator runs and updates the database to see the news from the feed he subscribed. What I want to do is to securely send a message from the php script to the aggregator issuing an exceptional feed update.

Answer (score 2):

Open a server socket in Java application. Then send the data over it. You may use SSL to secure the communication.

[Socket Communication in PHP](http://www.php.net/sockets)

[Socket Communication in Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use some well-established language agnostic remote communications protocols like SOAP or REST (both supported by java and php) or develop you own socket based solution.

Additional option might be [php-java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) which promises to be performance wise effective.

Answer (score 1):

If the java program is on the PHP server can't you just simply open a shell from php to run the java program with arguments to trigger the update ?

Comment: I expressed the idea incorrectly. The Java program is always running, only the update threads are running periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Would having the java app waiting for commands on a socket be an acceptable option?