# Migrating Ajax web application to web socket

Tags: java, php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I think I'm just missing a little detail that is preventing me from seeing the whole picture.

I have a web application which use ajax request every x time to update client with new information or tasks.

I also have a long running process on the server which is a java computation engine. I would like this engine to send update to the client.

1. I am wondering how to migrate my web app to using websocket. Probably [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) or similar. Can my server 'decide' to send information to a specific client? It seems possible looking at the php-websocket.
2. Can my java backend long process use the websocket server to send notification to a specific client. How? well I can say that my java app could use a class that could send over websocket instead of http.

But how the websocket server knows to which client to send the 'info'. I am puzzle by all this. Any document that explain this in more details? It seems that the websocket could create an instance of my web application.

Thanks

Comment: fyi- some recent security issues with websockets you may want to read up on before coding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server, which will have an arbitrary number of active client sockets, decides which ones to write to (possibly in response to input from the user).

`phpwebsocket` (which is still very rough around the edges) has a [`User`](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/source/browse/trunk/+phpwebsocket/websocket.class.php?r=8#156) class with `$id`, `$socket` (this is the underlying TCP socket), and `$handshake` fields.  You could extend that class with additional metadata about the `User` (e.g. a computation identifier).  Or you could use an array mapping from computation id to `User`.

Perhaps when Java computation `n` finishes, you can look up the socket associated with that computation, and write to its socket.

Comment: My Java computation could "POST" to ws://mydomain/mysocketapp?user=xx;msg="completed". Then the websocket would find the corresponding user/socket and send "echo" the message to the user.

Comment: Keep in mind websockets don't use HTTP after connecting, unless you implement HTTP over the websocket.  You don't necessarily have to use websockets to communicate between your server and Java back-end.  You can use another form of inter-process communication.

Comment: Any pointer of inter-process communication i could look at and read more about?

Comment: @Bastan, you could look at Wikipedia's [ipc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) article for general information.  There is a [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661546/) specifically about communicating between PHP and Java programs.  As it notes, you could use regular HTTP (with both server and client on localhost), [TCP sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661546/661550#661550) (which pre-exist, and in fact underlay, WebSocket, and have better docs).  There's a also tool called [php/java bridge](http://goo.gl/B5ncU).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the Information. I was just reading something similar at http://mindprod.com/jgloss/remotefileaccess.html