# Print out shell_exec as it runs

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have created a small php script locally that runs a java application in command line. This java application continuously runs and never finishes. As it runs, it outputs command line text. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    $command = "java -Xms124M -Xmx124M -jar myapp.jar";
    $end = " 2>&1";
    $in = $command . $end;
    $out =  exec($in);
    var_dump($out);
?>
```

My problem is that the output is never printed because the app never stops running. Is there a way to get the php to print out each line that is returned as the app is running? 
Hopefully I am making sense here (Let me know if I am not).

Comment: Why are you spawning a process that isn't expected to end? Wouldn't a service-based or client-server architecture be better?

Comment: The 'java' tag is not relevant.  You'd have the same issue with long-running programs written in any language.

Comment: well, if the process never finishes then you need to open it in a different thread but afaik php has no build in multithreading capabilities. Since opening a JVM for each request is overkill anyways I'd suggest that you use some form of inter-process communication (IPC) to start a new instance of your program by doing something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661546/sending-messages-from-php-to-java .Also updating the site incrementally should be done via JavaScript and additional requests instead of waiting for one request. EDIT: well I didn't read the "locally" part, silly me

Comment: @Kenaniah I don't quite know what you mean by that. Do you mean a different language (Python or C) or different hardware / OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [`passthru`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) function and the [`popen`](http://us.php.net/popen) function.  These should return output as it occurs (although passthru might buffer the output).

Comment: In this case it means it sends back the output in chunks rather then as it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to launch your process as a background process and redirect output to a file. You could then read the output file in PHP, but you really shouldn't leave PHP running like that, especially since your java process is expected to never end. A better solution would be to use AJAX polling to have PHP return any recent updates to the output file every few seconds or something.